# LinearLayout color changing (Smooth animation)

Tags: android, animation, colors, fade

I have a `LinearLayout` with an initial `background` (lets say : `#ff4455`) and I want the `background` color to change to another value when clicking a `button`in Smooth way (FADE) .. How to do that ..

NOTE : I have FOUR buttons, each button will change the background to another color..

Answer (score 0):

Use a value animator

```
int[] colors = new int[]{...} // create an array with colors for each button

button1.setOnClickListener(v -> updateBackgroundColor(0)); 
button2.setOnClickListener(v -> updateBackgroundColor(1)); 
button3.setOnClickListener(v -> updateBackgroundColor(2)); 
button4.setOnClickListener(v -> updateBackgroundColor(3)); 

private void updateBackgroundColor(int buttonPos) {
    Drawable background = view.getBackground();
    if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
        color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
    int colorFrom = color == null ? defaultColor : color;
    int colorTo = colors[buttonPos];
    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
    colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
});
colorAnimation.start();
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions and if you have success please accept and upvote

Comment: what are the format of the colors values,, Color.valueOf(0xffff0000)

Comment: Yea that would work, it should be the actual color value.  I would recommend `ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.myColor1);` so you can store your colors in a colors xml file

Comment: but it doesnt work, it says Found int Required android.graphic.color

Comment: Oh yea sorry for the array make it an array of int[]